# Asynchronous atomic array

Tags: java, list, asynchronous

I have a critical section of my (Java) code which basically goes like the snippet below. They're coming in from a nio server.

```
void messageReceived(User user, Message message) {
    synchronized(entryLock) {
        userRegistry.updateLastMessageReceived(user,time());
        server.receive(user,message);
    }
}
```

However, a high percentage of my messages are not going to change the server state, really. They're merely the client saying "hello, I'm still here". I really don't want to have to make that inside the synchronization block.

I could use a synchronous map or something like that, but it's still going to incur a synchronization penalty.

What I would really like to do is to have something like a drop box, like this

```
void messageReceived(User user, Message message) {
    dropbox.add(new UserReceived(user,time());
    if(message.getType() != message.TYPE_KEPT_ALIVE) {
        synchronized(entryLock) {
            server.receive(user,message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a cleanup routine to automatically put clients that aren't active to sleep. So instead of synchronizing on every kept alive message to update the registry, the cleanup routine can simply compile the kept alive messages in a single synchronization block.

So naturally, reconigizing a need for this, the first thing I did was start making a solution. Then I decided this was a non-trivial class, and a problem that was more than likely fairly common. so here I am.

tl;dr Is there a Java library or other solution I can use to facilitate atomically adding to a list of objects in an asynchronous manner? Collecting from the list in an asychronous manner is not required. I just don't want to synchronize on every add to the list.

Comment: Does your dropbox need to track all the "hi I'm still here" messages from a user, or just the last one?  If the later, you could use a Map<User, Date> to store them, and overwrite any previous.  Avoids a few of the "this may grow really large" issues.  Obviously you'd need a Map that handles concurrency.

Comment: @user949300: I think the dropbox OP's talking about needs to track *all* the messages, including the ones that are not heartbeats.  Now maybe that only the last heartbeat would be ok, but the dropbox would still need to contain all the messages that are not heartbeats.  *(at least that's what the code above looks like)*

Comment: @user949300 It does only need the last one. However, I anticipated (perhaps wrongly) that it would be incredibly difficult to find an atomic map. I do have the map you describe in my code already, but I don't want updates to it to be in the synchronized block (unless I'm doing them all in a single block.) I think that addresses 988052's comments as well.

Comment: @glowcoder Have you looked at ConcurrentMap / ConcurrentHashMap?  May do what you want.  ConcurrentHashMap is optimized for non-blocking retrieval, not for non-blocking update, so that may be non-ideal, but it may be good enough.  I don't know if there is a version optimized the other way.  Oops - just saw you had commented below.  Maybe Google for an alternative that is non-blocking on put (but possibly blocking on take).

Comment: @user949300 I have looked into it, but it's not suitable due to its blocking nature. :-(

Comment: O.K.  A little Googling found http://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/javadoc/concjunit4.7/org/cliffc/high_scale_lib/NonBlockingHashMap.html.  Caveat Emptor.  :-)

Comment: @glowcoder Sorry, dude, but I don't think you understand what "blocking" means. "Blocking" is not necessarily slower than "non-blocking", and you should look for the data-structure that gives you the best concurrency and performance for your needs whether it's locking or lock-free.

Comment: @pron I do have a keen understanding of blocking and nonblocking. Essentially we're willing to incur busy waiting in order to avoid the system putting a thread in a wait state. That's a trade off I'm willing to make. At the very least, I'd like to be able to test both alternatives to determine which is better.

Comment: @user949300 pron beat you to it :) I've already plugged it into my app, and I'm really liking it so far.

Comment: @glowcoder Good luck, then! Just remember that a concurrent map only allows you to replace values atomically. You can't, for example, increment a number that's stored in the map atomically.

Comment: @pron that's fine (although I could retreive the value object and reset the internal state of that value object... so essentially I could. Although in that light perhaps ConcurrentHashMap, with its nonblocking retrieval would work for me... It's almost as if someone else has done this before and has determined what really needs to be in the standard library and what doesn't or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are few things you must bear in mind.

First, there is very little "synchronization cost" if there is little contention (more than one thread trying to enter the synchronized block at the same time).

Second, if there is contention, you're going to incur some cost no matter what technique you're using. Paul is right about [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and the "wait-free" means that thread concurrency control is not done using locks, but still, you will always pay some price for contention. You may also want to look at [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) because I'm not sure a list is what you're looking for. Using both classes is quite simple and common.

If you want to be more adventurous, you might find some non-locking synchronization primitives in [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).

Comment: I considered a CHashMap from the start, but its a locking map which is what I'm trying to avoid. I think Paul's recommendation is going to get the job done, but in all honesty a non-locking map would be the 'perfect' solution.

Comment: Oh, for a non-locking map, take a look at Cliff Click's [high-scale-lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib/). It's got a non-locking map called NonBlockingHashMap. But, frankly, I don't think you quite understand your problem if you think that both a map or a queue would do the job (you'd want one or the other), and, more importantly, from the fact that you insist on not using locks. Any synchronization entails a cost whether it's using a lock or not. Sometimes locks are faster than the non-locking solution.

Comment: And if you want to just update counters atomically, and you know the maximum number of clients in advance, you won't get any faster than [AtomicIntegerArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html)

Comment: I recognize that using a list instead of the map doesn't fully solve my problem. But it does provide a decent workaround for the problem.

Comment: I don't think so. Using a queue like a map would give you far worse performance than any synchronized map or concurrent-map out there. Take a look at my previous two comments about NonBlockingHashMap and AtomicIntegerArray.

Comment: I've looked at cliff's NBHashMap and have determined it is indeed the 'perfect' solution I was looking for. I really like it!

Comment: @glowcoder Great! Now, maybe you'd want to read a little bit about what lock-free and wait-free [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-free_and_wait-free_algorithms). It's a complex subject, and sometimes the locking data-structure are faster.

Answer (score 2):

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) claims to be:

> This implementation employs an efficient "wait-free" algorithm based on one described in Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking Concurrent Queue Algorithms by Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott.

I'm not sure what the quotes on "wait-free" entail but the Concurrent* classes are good places to look for structures like you're looking for.

You might also be interested in the following: [Effective Concurrency: Lock-Free Code — A False Sense of Security](http://herbsutter.com/2008/08/05/effective-concurrency-lock-free-code-a-false-sense-of-security/). It talks about how hard these things are to get right, even for experts.

Comment: That's exactly why I don't want to have to do it myself. Sure, I'm pretty good with concurrency. But I'm not Joshua Bloch. If there's an engineer that does nothing but this stuff for years at a time, I'd rather use their library if I can. That CLQueue looks promising, I will look into that for sure. I'll also take a peek at that blog post you linked. Hopefully it has libraries in it, but if it doesn't it should at least have common pitfalls. Thanks!

Comment: It's a good answer, just not for this question. This is really not what glowcoder needs for this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we could do is to use a simple ArrayList for keep-alive messages:

1. Keep adding to this list whenever each keep-alive message comes.
2. The other thread would synch on a lock X and read and process
   keep-alives. Note that this thread is not removing from list only
   reading/copying.
3. Finally in messageReceived itself you check if the list has grown
   say beyond 1000, in which case you synch on the lock X and clear the
   list.

   List keepAliveList = new ArrayList();
   void messageReceived(User user, Message message) {
           if(message.getType() == message.TYPE_KEPT_ALIVE) {
              if(keepAliveList.size() > THRESHOLD) {
                 synchronized(X) {
                     processList.addAll(list);
                     list.clear();
                 }
               }
              keepAliveList.add(message);
           }
   }

//on another thread
void checkKeepAlives() {
     synchronized(X) {
         processList.addAll(list)
     }
     processKeepAlives(processList);
}

Comment: But is adding to an ArrayList atomic? If two threads try to add to it at the same time, is one of them going to get lost?

Comment: @glowcoder you are right, adding to a list is not atomic. missed that